# Como testar conexao em swift

Tags: ios, swift

Tenho uma webview bem simples, e antes de carregar a webview quero checar a conexao, caso esteja indisponivel crie uma mensagem para o usuario informando.

Comment: Uma das grandes vantagens do *Swift* é a possibilidade de utilizar códigos em *Objective-C*, ou seja, você ainda consegue utilizar o [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) em conjunto. De outra forma, esse cara também fez [algo semelhante](https://github.com/Isuru-Nanayakkara/Swift-Reachability) com o próprio *Swift* desta mesma biblioteca.

Comment: o uso if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() {
            networkStatusLabel.text = "Internet Connection: Available"
            networkStatusLabel.textColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        } else {
            networkStatusLabel.text = "Internet Connection: Unavailable"
            networkStatusLabel.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
        }  isso ja resolve?

Answer (score 2):

A melhor solução é você não testar mas sim, esperar da erro para tomar uma decisão.

Testar se o usuário tem conexão, não significa que depois do teste, sua tomada de decisão estará correta, por que a conexão pode mudar de status durante a execução da decisão tomada, logo você pode cair no mesmo problema.

Exemplo com um pseudo código:

```
testConnection({ hasConnection in
  if hasConnection {
    getContentOnline()
  }
  else {
    getContentOffline()
  }
})
```

1. O callback não vai executar de imediato, você vai precisar esperar, ou seja, pode demorar.
2. Não é 100% já que a conexão pode parar de responder durante o request e ai você vai cair no mesmo problema.

Como disse, você não precisa testar, o que você precisa é implementar um fallback, caso o app não consiga carregar os dados e neste caso, você precisa implementar o método `- webView:didFailLoadWithError:` do `UIWebViewDelegate`.

Abaixo estão os motivos por falha ou falta de conexão de dados do device, que você consegue trata-los facilmente usando um `switch`:

```
// assumindo que você receba um erro do callback webView:didFailLoadWithError
switch ([error code]){
  case NSURLErrorInternationalRoamingOff:
  case NSURLErrorCallIsActive:
  case NSURLErrorDataNotAllowed:
  case NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet:
  // Testar falha de rede com Reachabiity
  break;

  default:
  break;
}
```

Se você recebeu um desses códigos, você pode usar Reachability para:

1. Para testar se o host está "*reachable*", se sim, você pode tentar de novo ou pedir para o usuário tentar de novo (com um botão de recarregar por exemplo).
2. Para mostrar que o usuário está offline.
3. Para avisar ao usuário que a rede dele está com problemas.

Eu uso bastante esse approach pra praticamente tudo de networking, isso mantêm seu app sempre responsivo, rápido e não fica onerando dados e tempo do usuário com teste.

Espero que ajude, bom coding.